# Vertices Rigging Problem

Tags: mesh, rigging, bones, vertices

I'm still new to rigging. So, for the last few hours I've been trying to rig this cloth but there's a small problem that keeps bugging me.[image]

Whenever I move the head bone ( I used Mixamo's rig) there are parts of the cloth that sticks to it, making a terrible deformation. Worst part is, I don't know what the problem is because there are other active meshes that are much closer to the bone but doesn't get this problem (example: outer layer coat). Can anyone help with this? I've been searching for a solution but there seems to be no answer in the internet.

Answer (score 0):

Some vertices of this part are probably assigned to the head bone vertex group or to the one that is above. To fix that, activate the 2 first options on the top of your *Armature* modifier, select the dysfunctionnal vertices in *Edit* mode, go into *Object Data > Vertex Groups*, select the vertex group of the head and click on the *Remove* button under the vertex groups list, same for the vertex group related to the top bone